Good Practice for Updating Client-side Data after CRUD Operations with Angular and API Requests
I'm developing an Angular application that communicates with a server via API requests.
I have a component that stores a collection of objects received from the server. And currently, after each CRUD operation (create, read, update, delete), I'm fetching the entire collection of objects from the server again that includes this modieed/added object.
So, my question is:
Is it considered a normal practice to fetch the entire collection of elenets from the server after each CRUD operation or it would be better to locally update the client-side collection with the modified/added object.
Sample code below.
Thank you.
class SampleComponent {

    collection: any = [];

    constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {
    }

    // Approach 1
    addElement(newElement: any) {
        this.sampleService.addElement(newElement).subscribe(e => {
            this.sampleService.findAllElements(collection => this.collection = collection);
        });

    }

    // Approach 2
    addElement(newElement: any) {
        this.sampleService.addElement(newElement).subscribe(e => {
            this.collection.push(e);
        });
    }
}


Think about a scenario where your app has multiple users, each will perform crud operations, so
Scenario: Manager informs team to update at least 10000 billing amount to one of the rows.

User 1 and User 2 open the screen simultaneously
User 1 updated billing amount to 10000 of row 1
User 2 updated billing amount to 10000 of row 2

When user 2 has the logic of updating only one row. I will look like user2 was the first person to refresh the amount to 10000, even though user1 executed it first!
When user 2 has the logic of refreshing the entire table. It will reflect that user 1 already performed an update on one row for 10000, so user 2 can revert their update.
So long story short, refresh the entire dataset to avoid stale data being shown to the end user!
We can also update the realtime updates using websockets and other technologies, but above method is the simplest solution I feel

But user2 may still see old/irrelevant data even if I always fetch the whole collection.

User2 receives the list from the server
User1 receives the list from the server
User1 updates rows 1 and 2
User2 updates rows 1 and 2 (he updates the already updated rows, but he does not see this)


@MarkIgushkin Yes, for that you need to have a dynamic real time updating table, which will involve complex websockets and might be overkill, plus the user by habit will refresh the screen if its open for a long time, as a safety we can do a refresh after any crud operation done, if we update only 1 row, there is a possibility that multiple updates on rows will not be seen by the end user!

no it is not a normal practice every time you work with CRUD Operation,
it's better if you use approach 2 and update your object inside component
and use spread operator instead of collection.push()
addElement(newElement: any) {
    this.sampleService.addElement(newElement).subscribe(e => {
       // I use spread operator instead of push for updating
        this.collection = [...this.collection, e];
      // for when you want to delete element from collection
        const indexToRemove = this.collection.indexOf(e);
        this.collection.splice(indexToRemove, 1); 
    });
}


It is relevant in both cases,here in approach 1 is clean and stateless, when you change some object and you get a confirmation on the success you are simply fetching all the data regardless of the state. this simply ensures the correct data is fetched from the server each time.
(i usually use approach one, not only to avoid the state maintenance hassle but also for its simplicity, but please do consider the fetch time of the List API, if it takes less than a second or so please go for this approach or else go for the approach 2, make sure the list is paginated)
while considering the Approach 2, it is useful when time or size of list API is high, so that you just have to append the object to the list and continue the operation. also can consider when performance is a factor.
Hope this helps :)
